# Resolve IP address from CNAME record with Powershell

Tags: powershell, dns

My servers have recently moved from a simple `www.example.com A 10.10.10.10` type structure to using CNAME abstraction....

```
 www.example.com   CNAME   www1.example.com
 www1.example.com      A   10.10.10.10
```

Previously I could do a DNS lookup to get the A record using:

```
 $myHostIp = Resolve-DnsName "www.example.com" A -DnsOnly | Select-Object -first 1
 $myHostIp = $myHostIp.IP4Address
```

(this doesn't work with the CNAME records).

How do I get the (first) IP address associated with a CNAME record?

I tried:

```
 $myHostIp = Resolve-DnsName "www.example.com" A -DnsOnly | Select-Object -first 1 -Property IP4Address
```

But I just get null.

Comment: Don't have a Win10/PS5 box on hand to test at the moment, but perhaps the Get-DnsServerResourceRecord cmdlet can provide you that information

Comment: @trebleCode: if I ran it in a loop until to resolved the CNAME chain, then yes - but I'd rather keep the script minimal unless it gets rather esoteric.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you query a CNAME with `Resolve-DnsName -Type A`, you get two responses. The first is the CNAME response, and the second is the A.

You can see clearly what happens like so:

```
PS> Resolve-DnsName -Name 'www.google.com' -Type A -DnsOnly | Format-List -Property *


QueryType    : CNAME
Server       : forcesafesearch.google.com
NameHost     : forcesafesearch.google.com
Name         : www.google.com
Type         : CNAME
CharacterSet : Unicode
Section      : Answer
DataLength   : 8
TTL          : 228

Address      : 216.239.38.120
IPAddress    : 216.239.38.120
QueryType    : A
IP4Address   : 216.239.38.120
Name         : forcesafesearch.google.com
Type         : A
CharacterSet : Unicode
Section      : Answer
DataLength   : 4
TTL          : 228
```

You're getting a null because the first object does not contain a property called "IP4Address", and the value of properties which do not exist is null.

Try:

```
$myHostIp = Resolve-DnsName -Name 'www.example.com' -Type A -DnsOnly | 
    Where-Object QueryType -eq 'A' |
    Select-Object -First 1 -ExpandProperty IP4Address
```

Comment: That looks nicer than my solution, and a better explanation of what went wrong  - I'll need to do a bit of testing to make sure it is as transparent as it appears.

Comment: @symcbean I would think this would be cleaner than just picking the second  one. CNAMEs can point to other CNAMEs. It's not a common (or particularly good) practice, but it's technically allowed.  You could also filter with `Where-Object IP4Address -ne $null`.  That might be even better if you have some hosts which are IPv6 only.

Comment: The A record should always be the last to be returned (in terms of causality) but I've not seen documentation to say that the ordering would be preserved. Using the Where-object cuts out the stuff I'm definitely not interested in - so I'm using a combination of that and `Select-object -last`

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution.

Resolve-DnsName was returning two records in place of the 1 it had done previously - the first was for the CNAME record with a null IP address property, but the second was correctly populated, so I changed `Select-Object -first` for `Select-Object -last`.

I'll leave the question open to see if someone else has a smarter solution.